# Submit on enter with React

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to have my form submit when the user uses enter. Right now it just refreshes and brings me to the endpoint /?. I had everything working before when I just had it working off click.

```
 class NavBar extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          term: ''
        }
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange(e) {
  this.setState({
      term: e.target.value
  });
}

search() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.props.searchrequest(this.state.term);
}

render() {
    return (
                <form onSubmit={this.search}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    <button type="submit" >Search</button>
                </form>
      )}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `event` argument in your `search` function. Use it like this:

```
search( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.props.searchrequest(this.state.term);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the event object as the first argument in this.search

`search(event) { event.preventDefault()}`

Answer (score 0):

Use event.preventDefault() in your submit event handler. (It's missing "event" in its argument)